# phpmyadmin share specific DB with more machines

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm doing a web project and im using `wamppserver` to take care of the server and database. And now I'm facing a problem, I have to share the project. So it would be  useful if i could share the specific DB that I use in the project, so that other people can access from their machines and get all the data previously stored in the DB. Is it possible to do it? How?

Comment: You're talking about other machines accessing the database on your machine, or giving it a copy of the database?

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto I'm talking about other machines accessing the database on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to grant access to other machines to one database on local mysql server, you need to do some things:

1. You need to open MySQL to network interface: Check my.cnf, and do this:

   - Comment the line skip-networking.
   - Change the line bind-address to hold your LAN IP address / WAN IP address (if the machine itself have the WAN IP) / 0.0.0.0 (for all IPv4 addresses of the machine) / :: (for all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of the machine). After reconfigure, restart MySQL server.
2. Check / configure your firewall for port 3306 opened (You can configure firewall for accept connections only from the required IPs) (Configuration for doing this will depend on your firewall software).
3. Grant access to the user(s) from the IPs you will need.

   - You can give access to one user from all IPs, for doing this, execute command [1] on MySQL cli or phpmyadmin, with a user with SUPER privileges (usually root).
   - You can give access to one user from one IP. Execute command [2].

> [1]: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
>
> [2]: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

You need to replace database with the name of the database to give privileges, user with the username accessing, host with the IP address of the client accessing, and password, with the desired password.

You can also, repeat command [2] if you want the same username to have access from two different IPs for example. Also, you can use a combination of [1] and [2], using a host with this example format: @'192.168.0.%', for giving access to these user from all computers on the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

Also, you can give really fine privileges, for example, changing GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES with GRANT SELECT, INSERT, these user only can do SELECT and INSERT statements, but not UPDATE or DELETE ones for example. You can check MySQL doc or StackOverflow for more info about this.